# cannot access nodeJS REST API on google cloud ubuntu 16.04 instance but I can ping on the public IP successfully

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server, google-cloud-console

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 instance on google cloud and I can ping the instance with it's public IP, I'm trying to run a nodeJS backend REST-API on it.. I have successfully check API on my local machine, along with mongoDB.

In terminal connection I can see nodeJS my server (API) is running, but I cannot access to it. I have try API calls by using web browsers and postman, but it giving following error after few seconds delay "Could not get any response - There was an error connecting to :" how to solve the issue and what might be the cause for this problem.

Comment: did you open the port through the fire wall ?

Comment: Thanks Kalana, that was the error, and I could fixed it by adding new rule for firewall !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the necessary port in firewall rules section

Go to -> Cloud console -> Networking ->  VPC networks -> Firewall Rules

Click create Firewall rules, Add a name, keep the rest in default and in the source ip ranges add 0.0.0.0/0 and in the Specified protocols and ports add tcp:<"your app port">

Comment: Great Thanks ! That was the problem... and it's working now after creating new firewall rules.... :D

Comment: Thanks! You saved me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kalana's answer, you should also add http-server in target tags.